# Setting Height of the content in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, web, layout, bootstrap-4

I called two columns in `bootstrap`, suppose the height of one column is `800 PX`, and then i want the text in second column to start after the `height 200 PX`. what should i do? I don't want to use padding or margin. Is there any predefined class in the bootstrap for it? Please help, if any one could.

Comment: If you want to use bootstrap classes, you can use height class to do so instead of putting raw css in your html attribute.
I suggest you to take a look at the [bootstrap sizing documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/)

Comment: Share your problem on stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another div of size 200px then below it you can put your div to have a height of 600 (or 800).
Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="height:800;;background-color:yellow">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="height:200;background-color:blue">
    </div>    
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="height:600;background-color:black">
    </div>    
</div>
```